# TypeError: ... is not a function

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript code in NodeJS results in:

```
TypeError: ninja.changeName is not a function
```

Following is my code:

```
function Ninja(name){
  this.name = name;

  var changeName = function(name2) {
    this.name = name2;
  }
}

var ninja = new Ninja("John");
ninja.changeName("Bob");
console.log(ninja.name);
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: with all respect, I don't quite agree with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254096/4068240 , even as someone who has years of experience from the traditional OO world such as Java and have started to read JavaScript books, I can't for the life of me think of "attach the changeName to this"; why isn't a "var" declaration enough?

Comment: You don't quite agree with debugging code? What for god sake? If you have years of experience with OOP (or any other kind of write code and make things happen), the first thing you would read in JavaScript books would be _how to debug things_. And if you would have attached a debugger at this, there would be no need to ask this question. 
...Oh and this is one of the really real basics of how javascript "objects" work.

Comment: Oh and this one is definitely worth reading: http://blog.petdance.com/2012/04/18/the-worlds-two-worst-variable-names/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`var changeName` will just create a reference to a function which will be lost once the function is done executing.

You must assign the function as a property of the `Ninja` function instead:

```js
function Ninja(name) {
  this.name = name;

  this.changeName = function(name2) {
    this.name = name2;
  }
}

var ninja = new Ninja("John");
ninja.changeName("Bob");
console.log(ninja.name);
```

Comment: Accepted as answer for the key explanation of "var changeName will just create a reference to a function which will be lost once the function is done executing."; All other answers a correct but I still don't see the difference between a simple "var" declaration until I read this one.

Answer (score 3):

```
var changeName = function(name2) {
    this.name = name2;
  }
```

You are declaring a function but not attaching that to the object.

It should be

```
   this.changeName = function(name2) {
    this.name = name2;
  }
```

So that the property `changeName` as a function attached to the object.

Comment: What about `prototype`?

Comment: @AdamAzad Well, the code structure of OP clearly telling that, OP forgot to attach to object and not aiming at prototype.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a function to a variable. This isn't the same as setting a function in the objects prototypal inheritance structure and the variable `changeName` is only in scope within the context of `Ninja`.

You can assign the function to `this.changeName` (important that you're binding to `this`) like the following:

```
function Ninja(name){
  this.name = name;

  this.changeName = function(name2) {
    this.name = name2;
  }
}
```

Or you could use prototypes:

```
function Ninja(name){
  this.name = name;
}
Ninja.prototype.changeName = function(name2) {
  this.name = name2;
}
```

Although these approaches look fairly similar, the difference is very important. The first approach creates a new function for every `Ninja` created. The second approach will use the same function for each object. To look into the reason to use prototypal inheritance, there are various [blog posts](https://medium.com/@kevincennis/prototypal-inheritance-781bccc97edb) scattered around the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the changeName as a variable but not binding it with the 'Ninja', So I believe instead of using var, it should this. So the code becomes like this.

```
function Ninja(name){
this.name = name;

  this.changeName = function(name2) {
    this.name = name2;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Ninja(name){
      this.name = name;

    return {
     changeName : function(name2) {
        this.name = name2;
     }
   }
}
```

In your code changeName is not exposed if you want to access the private data you can try with the above snippet

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to make your function public available would be to first declare it private (Some prefer to use an underscore, like usual in .Net):

```
 function Ninja(name) {
   this._name = name;

   var _changeName = function(name) {
     this._name = name;
   }
 }
```

And then export it using return. Some might know this from the classical Java boilerplate *Getters and Setters*, where fields are declared private by default and Methods make them available:

```
function Ninja(name) {
    this._name = name;

    var _changeName = function (name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    return {
        changeName: _changeName,
        getName: function () {return _name;}
    }
}
```

...And now, use the object:

```
var ninja = new Ninja("John");
ninja.changeName("Bob");
console.log(ninja.getName());
```